# Question in the Proof of the Recursion theorem - why is $d(u)$ total Recursive?

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

I saw a proof for the Recursion Theorem (Fixed Point Theorem), in Soare's book, Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees (pag. 36), and I didn't understand something.

So the theorem states, that if $f$ is a recursive function, then there is a natural number, $n$, such that  $\varphi_n = \varphi_{f(n)}$, where $\varphi$ denotes the enumeration of the Partial Recursive functions.

In the proof, he defines a function, $d(u)$, in the following manner:
$$ \varphi_{d(u)}(z) = \begin{cases} \varphi_{\varphi_u(u)}(z) & \varphi_u(u)\downarrow\\\ \uparrow & o.w. \end{cases}$$

The part I don't understand, is why $d(u)$ is a $1:1$ total Recursive function, as stated in the book. Aparently it's due to the $s$-$m$-$n$ theorem, by I don't really understand why. If $\varphi_1(1)$ doesn't halt, wouldn't $d(1)$ not halt as well?

So my question is why $d(u)$ is a total Recursive function, and how one can prove that from the $s$-$m$-$n$ theorem.

Comment: Intuitively, $d(u)$ is the following program: "Run $\varphi_u(u)$. If it halts and outputs $c$, run $\varphi_c(z)$. If *that* halts and outputs $d$, halt and output $d$." For each $u$, this is a program - which is to say that $d$ is total. $d(u)$ may not be an *always halting* program, but that's fine, we just need it to be a "grammtically correct" program.

Comment: In the formula defining $d$, the right side defines a partial recursive function of $u$ and $z$. Apply the $s-m-n$ theorem to that (with $m=n=1$), and note that the $s-m-n$ function in that theorem is total recursive.